# irobot_create_2_1 for fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, irobot-create-2-1, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a iRobot Create that I wish to control using ROS. I have a Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS fuerte installed. From what I searched in the internet, I find that the brown university drivers for iRobot were developed for electric and there are no versions of that driver available for fuerte. However, I tried installing them using the following command,

> sudo apt-get install
> ros-fuerte-brown-drivers

and the drivers installed successfully. After installing this I was able to successfully launch the "irobot_create_2_1" driver using the command

> rosrun irobot_create_2_1 driver.py

Here's the problem. When I checked the info of the rosnode create, I get the following information.

```
ashok@nightFury:~$ rosnode info create
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/create]
Publications: 
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: None

Services: None


contacting node http://nightFury:53815/ ...
Pid: 7310
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

However, according to [tutorials](http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/Writing_A_Simple_Node_that_Moves_the_iRobot_Create_Robot) that use the **electric-brown-drivers**, I should be getting the following information.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/create]
Publications: 
 * /sensorPacket [irobot_create_2_1/SensorPacket]
 * /odom [nav_msgs/Odometry]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /tf [tf/tfMessage]

Subscriptions: 
 * /cmd_vel [unknown type]

Services: 
 * /turn
 * /circle
 * /demo
 * /leds
 * /tank
 * /brake
 * /dock


contacting node http://ut-1215N:51148/ ...
Pid: 8218
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

Can you please help me figure out why I'm not able to get the same information as the electric-brown-drivers? If there are other better ways to control the create can you also please guide me to them.

Thanks in advance,
Ashok

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47404/irobot_create_2_1-for-fuerte/) by [Ashok Elluswamy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3481/ashok-elluswamy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The maintainers of irobot_create_2_1 are no longer actively updating this package.  I would recommend looking at the turtlebot_driver in the turtlebot stack for interfacing with the Create.  If there is larger interest in using irobot_create_2_1, I can take a look at addressing this issue over the next few weeks.

---

Originally posted by [odestcj](https://answers.ros.org/users/313/odestcj/) with karma: 123 on 2012-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [River](https://answers.ros.org/users/549/river/) on 2013-01-15**:
For future readers: Although turtlebot_driver is the underlying code for the create on the turtlebot stack, turtlebot_node is what you want.http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_node

**Comment by [River](https://answers.ros.org/users/549/river/) on 2013-01-15**:
For future readers: Although turtlebot_driver is the underlying code for the create on the turtlebot stack, turtlebot_node is what you want.http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_node